# If statement based on url contains

Tags: php, regex

I know this is pretty basic to those who follow the php tag but I'm a learner working on my first plugin.

I'm generating meta tags based on what page the visitor is viewing.

Using php, how do I say

```
IF url contains "^/reports/view/*" then do this(),
Else do that()
```

I'm not asking about syntax of the IF statement I can figure that out. It's using a regular expression in php. The particular set of pages I'm trying to target start with `/reports/view/` and then have something after.

Here are some example pages I wish to target:

```
example.com/reports/view/somepage.php
example.com/reports/view/someotherpage.php
```

I've used `if ==` before but never contains in this sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no need for employing regex in this case: you can use [**strpos()**](http://php.net/strpos) method just fine:

```
if (strpos('/reports/view/', $url) === 0) {
  // $url begins with '/reports/view/'
}

if (strpos('/reports/view/', $url) !== FALSE) {
  // $url contains '/reports/view/' substring
}
```

Comment: These are different checks, example added.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks others too checking this answer because got there first.